# ConsoleKit reports active/is-local only on the second+ login

Tags: startup, pam, polkit, consolekit

Running KDE Frameworks 5, Plasma 5, using `sddm` as a display manager.

`ConsoleKit` and `PAM-linux` are both installed.

Upon login (using the `sddm` login screen), `ck-list-sessions` returns `FALSE` for both `is-local` and `active`. Only one session is present.

If I log out, then back in, the two fields are both `TRUE`, as expected.

`sddm` is not a console-kit supporting dm. Therefore, I am using the `pam_ck_connector.so` module to attach a consolekit session.

The sddm startup file (`/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsession`) is modified to launch using the line:

```
eval exec "ck-launch-session dbus-lauch --exit-with-session $session"
```

The (I think relevant) pam files are as follows:

`/etc/pam.d/sddm`:

```
auth            include         system-auth
account         include         system-account
password        include         system-password
session         include         system-session
session         optional        pam_loginuid.so
session         optional        pam_ck_connector.so nox11
session         optional        pam_warn.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/sddm-greeter`:

```
# Load environment from /etc/environment and ~/.pam_environment
auth            required pam_env.so

# Always let the greeter start without authentication
auth            required pam_permit.so

# No action required for account management
account         required pam_permit.so

# Can't change password
password        required pam_deny.so

# Setup session
session         required pam_unix.so
#session        optional pam_loginuid.so
session         optional pam_ck_connector.so
session         optional pam_warn.so
```

`pam_warn.so` lines have been added to force logging to the `/var/log/auth.log` file. A typical login looks something like:

```
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session opened for user sddm by (uid=0)
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_warn(sddm-greeter:session): function=[pam_sm_open_session] flags=0 service=[sddm-greeter] terminal=[:0] user=[sddm] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[<unknown>] 
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_unix(sddm:session): session opened for user <user-name> by (uid=0)
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_ck_connector(sddm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_warn(sddm:session): function= [pam_sm_open_session] flags=0 service=  [sddm] terminal=[:0] user=[<user-name>] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[<unknown>] 
<date/time> <pc-name> polkitd[810]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session4 (system bus name :1.38 [/opt/kde/lib64/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.ISO-8859-1)
```

How can I make my system start normally the first time?